# PSD to html dimentions

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, resolution, psd

I have a PSD which have 2600 PX as width, i would like to convert it to html css using bootstrap,
the PSD has a container centered with 2364px width, what css width should i use for this container?, i suppose i work for 1360x768 resolution.
I tried to get width by dividing by 2, supposing the screen width is 1360, 1360 ~= 2600/2, but it looks that the result is not conform to PSD. 
I would like to get width elements (paragraphs, images, ...) to use in css.

```
<div id="page">
        <div class="columns-container">
            <div id="columns" class="clearfix">
               <div  class="container">
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

and CSS

```
#page {
overflow: hidden;
background: #a4a4a4 !important;
} 
.columns-container {
margin-top: 32px;
 }
 #columns {
 padding: 0 0 30px 0;
 }
.container {
 width: 1170px;
 }
```

Sorry for my English.
Thanks

Comment: don't use `px` use `%`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but even bootstrap use px for the container element

Comment: Then perhaps you could customise Bootstrap - See [**Customise Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

Comment: so i should use margin and padding in % also?

Answer (score 0):

Tarek, Bootstrap using different widths for different view ports.

The basic width is 1174px in big screen. But the columns are in %. You don't need to convert it into percentage.

Please check the grid system and sample themes in [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) , You can re-write your html after that. All the best.

Comment: so for PSD with2364px container width which boostrap container width should i use?

Comment: obviously 2364px. is not browser compatible, so you can take the full width content as 100% and half width as 50%, and so on. for eg: in your PSD, is there a banner with 2364px can take as 100%.

Comment: Please check the structure of HTML5 and Bootstrap, you will surely get the idea.

Mainly grid system is like this, if you have 4 boxes horizontally in your design, in bootstrap grid system, (total area is parted as 12 columns/grids) you can divide the 12 grid by 4, then answer is 3, so 4 columns can write as `col-md-3` (3 column/grid x 4 = 12). for 2 boxes : `col-md-6`  Hope you get the idea.